# header.html added with ng-include loads late

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new in javascript. I'm making a simple website with a common header in the file header.html and I included it in each page of the site with ng-include.

My problem is that the content of the page loads first and then the header, that pushes the rest of the page down. Is there a way to make the header to load first?

Thanks

EDIT: I also include a footer that has the same problem.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle or codepen to debug easily

Comment: `ng-include` is async, and it can sometimes load after your main content.  a common solution is to load the template in the `run` block and insert the template into the template cache.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache#!/

Answer (score 0):

you can load header form external view

```
<div ng-include src="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

and then the rest of your app, notice you can put your angular refrence in head section

Comment: the ng-include works. The problem is that que main content of the page loads first and when the header apears it pushes down the rest of the page.

Comment: you can make a manual initialization to angular module after the header loaded  check 

[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try adding header via PHP include?

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>
```

I did find that most efficient way for my website and did the same with footer.

Comment: this isn't a solution for angular.js.  Angular can run on many platforms, not just php servers, and the question is about a client side option, not server side option.

Comment: i'm making a website without server side. Is it worth it to add one just to include the header and footer files?